# Instantiating/Accessing COM API from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, com, activex

I am trying to access a COM API of an application using Qt. However when I try to instantiate the COM API object I get:

```
D:\dev\git\com_example\Lights.h:441: error: undefined reference to `vtable for Lights::Application'
```

Now I know that this is normally associated with the fact that we have declared a method but not implemented it but I am using the Lights.tlb file provided by the SDK provider for the application and the Lights.h file referred to in the error message is auto-generated by Qt.

My .pro file is:

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets network widgets sql axcontainer

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = com_example
TEMPLATE = app
TYPELIBS = $$system(dumpcpp Lights.tlb)

HEADERS += \
    LightsInterface.h

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    LightsInterface.cpp
```

The TYPELIBS bit is what converts the Lights.tlb file to Lights.h and Lights.cpp

This is all fine, the code builds but as soon as I try to create an instance of the COM API interface I get the error. The code that does this is:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Lights.h"

class LightsInterface : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LightsInterface(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    Lights::Application app;
};

#endif // LIGHTSINTERFACE_H
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Are the Lights.h and Lights.cpp files not being generated correctly from the Lights.tlb file? Am I trying to instantiate the object incorrectly?

any help greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please share the lights.h, at least the relevant parts, like line 441. some lines before and after, the first few lines of the file, etc.

Comment: What's the definition of `Lights::Application`?  If it's a COM interface, then it needs to be a pointer.